# Scheduling / rotating images on a daily basis

Tags: channel, image

I have an area on my homepage for an image. I would like this image to change on a daily basis.

I would like to queue up images so they are ready.

I know i could set a channel for these images and schedule them via expiring etc, but I was thinking there must be an easier way!

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another simple idea...  Name your images like this:

```
December-1.jpg
December-2.jpg
December-3.jpg
```

Manually upload the images to the server... in your template call image like this:

```
<img src="/path/to/images/{current_time format="%F-%j"}.jpg">
```

The image for the current day will always be called.

---

EE date formatting options are here:
http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/date_variable_formatting.html

Comment: I like this idea! :)

Answer (score 6):

Your option is a good one and not hard at all.

Instead of expiring the entries, I would future date them and set limit="1" on your channel:entries tag. This way an entry will always appear. With expiring you risk human error causing an image not appearing.

Comment: Just trying to think this through. So say, for example, I want to upload 30 images (a months worth) I would set the entry date of each image one day ahead of the next. and set the limit to 1. Am I right in thinking that by setting the limit to 1, it would only display the most recently added image?

Comment: Set the entry date to the date/time you want the image to start showing on the site. Limit="1" will always show the entry with the most recent date.  Future dated entries won't show. The channel:entries tag defaults to ordering by date with most recent at top.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use channels, use low variables with a grid field with days of the week as the grid rows. Give each a file upload field and an alt field then use some logic on the template to get the day and call the low var for that day.

**Simple example, not verbatim code purely reference**

Grid field:

date_1    |    imgxx | alt title

date_2    |    imgyy | alt title

...

date_31   |    imgzz | alt title

```
{exp:low_variables:parse var="my_dates"}
{grid_field search:date_field="date_{current_time format="%j"}
<img src="{grid_field_img_column}" alt="{grid_field_alt_title}" />
{/grid_field}
{/exp:low_variables:parse}
```

Comment: Like the idea of using Low Variables for this, but wouldn't this method mean that I can only do 7 at a time?

Comment: Simply create 31 fields not 7 and you'd simply get the date (1,2,3...27,28 etc) and marry it to the corresponding low variable field, simple.

Comment: Thank you for the added example. I shall consider it, but I think initially (at least) i'm going to go with the direct solution posted.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, maybe this is a long shot if you want manual control, but to refresh an image once a day you could also try something like this:

{exp:channel:entries channel="images" cache="yes" refresh="1440" orderby="random"}
{/exp:channel:entries}

Comment: That would work, but I do want to control what images are showing when (for example, wintery photos in winter etc) rather then let it be randomised.